# How to run bootstrap's carousel interval function in component on vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-4, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to run a carousel interval function for Bootstrap 4's carousel in a component on Vue.js. When I paste to script tag in index.html, it works. But I can't run in a component. How can I run it?

the code I mentioned here:

```
$(".carousel").carousel({
    interval: 200
  });
```

```
<template>
  <div
    id="slider-1"
    class="carousel slide pull-full-screen"
    data-ride="carousel"
  >
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="../images/slides/cycling.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="../images/slides/diving.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="../images/slides/parachuting.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: where did you put `$(".carousel").carousel({
    interval: 200
  });`?

Comment: `#slider-1` named div